# Executing a windows application from php?

Tags: php, windows, iis

I'm trying to print an image that was rendered by my PHP script. To do this I am trying to use Irfanview (/print option).

I'm having trouble as there are security issues with executing and program from a script. I've tried adding IUSR to the usernames for the exe, but I juts get silence. I'm using the following:

```
pclose(popen('start /B .\i_view32.exe .\test.txt /print > res.txt 2> err.log', 'r'));
```

and

```
exec('.\i_view32.exe .\test.txt /print');
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Seems there use to be a safe mode you could disable, but I'm using PHP 5.4 and this has now been removed. There are lots of posts on the net for this, but they all seem to be outdated.

Comment: Specify absolute paths and check the permissions of the files and executables.

Comment: I've been through all that. Tried every combination I can run the PHP script from the command line. It's all about who's executing it. I understand it's a big security hole so I'm guessing that's why it's not possible(that I've found). The server won't be accessible to the Internet, so its a shame if I have to do something ugly like a schedule task script.